# Echo title attribute php

Tags: php, title, customization

I have the following in functions.php:

```
function twentyten_continue_reading_link() {
global $id;
return ' <span class="readmore"><a href="'. get_permalink($id) . '" title="' . the_title_attribute( array('echo' => 0, 'before' => 'Permalink to: ', 'after' => '')) . the_title() . '">' . __( 'Read More &#187;', 'twentyten' ) . '</a></span>';
}
```

which creates a "Read More" link after an excerpt with a title attribute.

I want to do the same thing in another part of the site, but the code for this 'Read More' link is different (see below). Since it's a php echo statement the same syntax won't work and I don't know how to translate what I have above to work in the situation below. I want to keep the href= $permalist[$j], but add a title attribute after it.

```
echo "<p class=\"readmore\"><a href=\"$permalist[$j]\">Read More &#187;</a></p>";
```

Answer (score 2):

Not exactly wordpress question, more of a php but -

The syntax for echo is quit simple :
You start with a quotation mark, and close with a quotation mark.
But since INSIDE the HTML we also need quotation marks , we separate them by using the single **`'`** for PHP and the double **`"`** for HTML. 
every time you have a php function, command, or variable, you should close the single quotation mark, place a DOT **`.`** and also put a dot **`.`** after, and re-open the single quotation mark if needed.  close all with semicolumn

So it would look like this :

```
echo ' <mytag class=" ' . $phpvariable . ' " title = " continueHtml " ' ;
```

in your case :

```
echo '<p class=\"readmore\"><a href=' . $permalist[$j] . ' title="your title" >Read More &#187;</a></p>';
```

OR

```
    echo "<h2><a href=\"$permalist[$j]\" >$titlelist[$j]</a></h2>";

 echo '<h2><a href="' . $permalist[$j] . '"/>' . $titlelist[$j] . '</a></h2>';
```

I am not familiar with **permalist[$j]** - does it being produced by you in any manner ?  or did you mean **permalink** ? or are you using some kind of plugin that produces it ?

#### Edit

Using your code above, just change the syntax, and use `the_title_attribute()`:

```
<?php
echo '<p class="readmore"><a href="' . $permalist[$j] . '" title="' . the_title_attribute( array( 'echo' => 0 ) ) . '">Read More &#187;</a></p>.;
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. permalist[$j] is a variable defined in the plugin (it's the permalink to the active slide in the content slider). I followed your suggestion but now the title attribute is displaying as `"' . the_title_attribute( array('echo' => 0, 'before' => 'Permalink to: ', 'after' => '')) . the_title() . '"` -- that code actually displays as the link title on hover. What am I doing wrong? Do I need to define `. the_title_attribute .` somewhere in the code before I use it?

Comment: can you please paste your whole code (relevant part)

Comment: See edited answer for example usage of `the_title_attribute()` in your code.